# how to loop retrieving data from covid library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
covid = Covid()
covid.get_data()       

confirmed = covid.get_total_confirmed_cases()
active = covid.get_total_active_cases()
recovered = covid.get_total_recovered()
deaths = covid.get_total_deaths()

@bot.group(invoke_without_command=True)
async def covid(ctx):
    em = discord.Embed(title = "Covid-19", description = "test", color = ctx.author.color) 
    em.add_field(name = "test2", value = active)#
    em.add_field(name = "test3", value = confirmed)
    em.add_field(name = "test4", value = deaths) 
    em.add_field(name = "test5", value = recovered) 

    await ctx.send(embed = em)
")
```

When the bot starts, it receives the current data from the library, and when it sends a message, it sends it, it receives it only once, and after launching it does not update this data anymore, I need to make sure that the data is updated and sent even when the bot is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just reload the data when the command is executed?

---

```
covidObject = Covid()


@bot.group(invoke_without_command=True)
async def covid(ctx):
    covidObject.get_data()       

    confirmed = covidObject.get_total_confirmed_cases()
    active = covidObject.get_total_active_cases()
    recovered = covidObject.get_total_recovered()
    deaths = covidObject.get_total_deaths()

    em = discord.Embed(title = "Covid-19", description = "test", color = ctx.author.color) 
    em.add_field(name = "test2", value = active)#
    em.add_field(name = "test3", value = confirmed)
    em.add_field(name = "test4", value = deaths) 
    em.add_field(name = "test5", value = recovered) 

    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'get_data'

Comment: Oh yeah, you should choose different names for your function and object. Didn't see that, I'll update my answer